# Facebook Default Share Button with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to show the default Facebook Share Button -- the one I get by [using their generated code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) -- with the Javascript SDK?

I need to subscribe to the [Share events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0) with the Javascript SDK, but I just want to use the regular default Share Button. My current solution will be to create my own version of the Share Button, and [wire it all up with the Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), but it's a lot of work when I just want the default.

Comment: Why do you need to subscribe to that event?

Comment: The business requirement is to record the Share in Google Analytics but only upon a successful Share.